# How do I get this terminal app to pass node test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

So this is a small terminal game, rock paper scissors, and I need help writing the remaining code so that it can pass my node tests. I have been able to code and input a decision for hand1 and hand2 and get a result displaying who won, but it won't seem to pass the node tests when I run them.

The node test detects the "tie" as correct, but doesn't detect the hands won or the scrub input as correct, yet it all works when I use it in terminal. [Here's an image of what the node test is saying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X2YQ.png)

The code needing to be rewritten is within function rockPaperScissors(hand1, hand2) below

```
    'use strict';

const assert = require('assert');
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});


function rockPaperScissors(hand1, hand2) {

  if (hand1 === hand2) {
    return "It's a tie!";
  } else if (hand1 === 'rock') {
    if (hand2 === 'paper') {
      return "Hand two wins!";
    } else if (hand2 === 'scissors') {
      return "Hand one wins!";
    } 
  }

  if (hand1 === 'paper') {
    if (hand2 === 'rock') {
      return "Hand one wins!";
    } else if (hand2 === 'scissors') {
      return "Hand two wins!";
    }
  }

  if (hand1 === 'scissors') {
    if (hand2 === 'paper') {
      return "Hand one wins!";
    } else if (hand2 === 'rock') {
      return "Hand two wins!";
    }
  }




}











function getPrompt() {
  rl.question('hand1: ', (answer1) => {
    rl.question('hand2: ', (answer2) => {
      console.log( rockPaperScissors(answer1, answer2) );
      getPrompt();
    });
  });
}

// Tests

if (typeof describe === 'function') {

  describe('#rockPaperScissors()', () => {
    it('should detect a tie', () => {
      assert.equal(rockPaperScissors('rock', 'rock'), "It's a tie!");
      assert.equal(rockPaperScissors('paper', 'paper'), "It's a tie!");
      assert.equal(rockPaperScissors('scissors', 'scissors'), "It's a tie!");
    });
    it('should detect which hand won', () => {
      assert.equal(rockPaperScissors('rock', 'paper'), "Hand two wins!");
      assert.equal(rockPaperScissors('paper', 'scissors'), "Hand two wins!");
      assert.equal(rockPaperScissors('rock', 'scissors'), "Hand one wins!");
    });
    it('should scrub input to ensure lowercase with "trim"ed whitepace', () => {
      assert.equal(rockPaperScissors('rOcK', ' paper '), "Hand two wins!");
      assert.equal(rockPaperScissors('Paper', 'SCISSORS'), "Hand two wins!");
      assert.equal(rockPaperScissors('rock ', 'sCiSsOrs'), "Hand one wins!");
    });
  });
} else {

  getPrompt();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **trim** and **lowercase** the values of `hand1` and `hand2` parameters:

```js
function rockPaperScissors(hand1, hand2) {
  hand1 = hand1.trim().toLowerCase();
  hand2 = hand2.trim().toLowerCase();
  ...
```

The **trim** function remove extra spaces from text. **toLowerCase** function convert all character in lower case.

now, your `rockPaperScissors` function look like:

```js
function rockPaperScissors(hand1, hand2) {
  hand1 = hand1.trim().toLowerCase();
  hand2 = hand2.trim().toLowerCase();

  if (hand1 === hand2) {
    return "It's a tie!";
  } else if (hand1 === 'rock') {
    if (hand2 === 'paper') {
      return "Hand two wins!";
    } else if (hand2 === 'scissors') {
      return "Hand one wins!";
    } 
  }

  if (hand1 === 'paper') {
    if (hand2 === 'rock') {
      return "Hand one wins!";
    } else if (hand2 === 'scissors') {
      return "Hand two wins!";
    }
  }

  if (hand1 === 'scissors') {
    if (hand2 === 'paper') {
      return "Hand one wins!";
    } else if (hand2 === 'rock') {
      return "Hand two wins!";
    }
  }




}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped out alot.